# Cannot Delete JPEG Image Files

Tags: windows, jpeg

I have a very odd issue with one machine.  It seems to not want to delete JPEG files.  If I try and delete it from within the Windows GUI, it just comes up with the estimating delete time and never proceeds beyond that.  I have to kill explorer.exe to get it to disappear.  I cannot delete it from a command prompt either nor from another machine.  All methods just cause the process trying to delete the file to hang.  This is not specific to a single image file so I know it's not a physical disk issue.  I am wondering if there might be some sort of DLL registered to handle JPEG files and maybe it is screwing up?

Comment: What version of Windows do you use? So basically you can delete anything else? Are the images write protected? Are the images stored locally on your PC or on a network share?

Comment: This is a Windows 7 machine and everything else can delete fine.  The images are not write protected and they work correctly (ie: I can display them fine).  They are stored locally on the PC.

Comment: Can you edit them? Rename and open with paint do some changes and than save? Also can you try if you can delete them is you run Windows in safe mode?

Comment: Well, I went to try deleting one image and now it deleted fine so I'm really confused.  I will have to play around with this more tomorrow.

Comment: Probably it was being used by another service/program that caused the trouble. There might be something that you turned off or have not started yet

Comment: I've had this problem before and I don't know what causes it but the solution is to download a 3rd party shredder and shred these files...You won't have any problems after that.

Comment: @Divin3: I don't think so... Normally if a file is in use Windows will come back and tell you that.  In my case the delete process just hangs which is not normal.

Comment: @Private: I haven't tried one of those apps yet but you're right.  I'll try one tomorrow.